# WooCommerce 2.6.4 shipping calculator not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to get the shipping calculator working in the webshop I'm creating, and it doesn't seem to be working properly. For our base location (Netherlands), I've set up a shipping zone with a flat & free rate. This option seems to be working perfectly.

However we also have a shipping zone for all other countries in Europe (higher flat rate), and whenever I change the country to any other country and try to calculate shipping, it still returns the same shipping cost as in the Netherlands shipping zone.

Does anyone else have this problem or a nice workaround?

What I've tried so far:

- Cleared all sessions, shipping debug mode, WC Transients.
- Tried 2 different themes to see if the shipping calculator is working (not the case).

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed:

Apparently you have to re-order the shipping zones, in my case Netherlands was 1st, but now i switched it with Europe and it works.